# Can't get submit button to do anything in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've been trying to learn ASP.NET Core Razor Pages with MVC and I am struggling with getting the submit button to do anything.

Here is my .cshtml code:

```
@page
@model MyClientBuddy.Pages.Index1Model

<form name="AddNewClient" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstNameTextBox" placeholder="First Name" /></td>
                    
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Client" asp-action="AddNewClient" name="saveButton" value="Save">

                    </td>
                </tr>
</form>
```

I made a controller class named "ClientController.cs" and put it in the "Controllers" folder.

This is what the class looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyClientBuddy.Controllers
{

    public class ClientController : Controller
    {


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddNewClient(string submitButton)
        {
            //Do stuff...
            return RedirectToAction("Clients");
        }
    }
}
```

I think the submit button is not properly linking the controller with the button and the action I want played never executes. Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Use the F12 console to confirm that the button is posting. Use the debugger in Visual Studio to confirm that the method is called and step through it.

Comment: Add asp-controller and asp-action to your form instead of your button and see the result.

Comment: move `asp-controller` and `asp-action` attributes to `form` tag

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure you have added routing of mvc in Program.cs.Without configuring the routing,it will not go to the controller:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
...

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```